# JBoss 6.0 M3 and Log4j logging

Tags: jboss6.x

I'm trying to have application specific logging plus the usual server logs seperately. I have specified 2  in the jboss-logging.xml, one for my app and the other one is usual "server.log" file.

Issue is, both of the log files are getting created and logged at the same time. Can any one help me, what is the change i need to make to log ONLY application specific logs in my logfile?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. I was defining my application's handler on the  section in jboss-logging.xml.Plus i was defining a logger category for my app. The fix was, i removed my application's handler reference from `<root-handler>` section and hold just the logger category for my app as below:

```
 <logger category="com.X.Y.logger">
      <level name="DEBUG"/>
      <handlers>
         <handler-ref name="myApp"/>
      </handlers>
   </logger>
```